# Trying to center two text boxes with text-align

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center two text boxes with text-align. However, they didn't align center as you can see in this image. https://gyazo.com/c47f4037ba1ab3abef5833358d94172e
What caused the problem? What is the solution?

Here is my code:

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <input type="text">
  <br>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```css
input {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The main reason for the miss alignment is the white space between both inputs and more precisely between the first input and the `br`. If your remove it will be fine:

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <input type="text"><br>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Here is another example to clearly show the whitespace issue:

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <input type="text">
  <br>
  <input type="text">
  <br>
</div>
```

We added another `br` at the end which make us having white space after the first input AND the second input unlike perviously where the white space is only after the first one.

Adding border will show us those white spaces:

```html
<div style="text-align:center;display:inline-block;border:1px solid;">
  <input type="text">
  <br>
  <input type="text">
  <br>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center;display:inline-block;border:1px solid;">
  <input type="text">
  <br>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Issue in Chrome, but not in FF.

Comment: @VXp yes, they don't handle the white space the same when it comes to line break .. I remember an old question about this, need to find it now

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in order to center elements within a div:

```
#yourDiv {
    display: block;
    margin: 2px auto;
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Here is the code snippet of your modified code:

```html
<div style="display:block; margin: 2px auto; height: 20px; width: 200px;">
  <input type="text">
  <br>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is set a width to the parent, here it is `div` and then make the `width` of the `input` as `100%` as in the following solution. Use `margin: 0 auto;` instead of `text-align: center;` and you will achieve what you want to.

```css
.parent-div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30%;
}

.parent-div input{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <input type="text">
  <br>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Thanks.